# Recognize particular id in ajax form mvc3 from several hyperlink

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am currently working on a MVC3 project. I currently stuck on this portion.

I have this Ajax form which contains several hyperlink

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Click", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "showpage" }))
{
     <a href="#" id="0" onclick='document.forms[0].submit()'>Link 0</a>
     <a href="#" id="1" onclick='document.forms[0].submit()'>Link 1</a>
}
```

I have this function called "Click" in a controller to fire whenever there'a link clicked.

```
public ActionResult Click(String id)
{
   // Action here
}
```

However, Whenever I click one of the hyperlinks, the click function receive id as "null". I want the function to know which hyperlink is click when enter the controller. Help needed :(

Comment: you are submitting the form. Model binders looks for the input named "id" to bind with your method, as you dont have input named "id" you are getting null.

Comment: I am sorry, but could you explain more about it? I am pretty new here. :/

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: basically my link is covered by image. Therefore whenever there's a link/image clicked by user, the function will be able to identify the link/image id to fire something....

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, I ***think*** you're after something like this:

**HTML**:

```
    <div id="showpage">
    </div><br />
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Click", "", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "showpage" }, 
               new { @id = "myAjaxForm" }))
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Link 0", "Click", null, new { @id = "Link0", @data_val = "0", @class = "links" })
        @Html.ActionLink("Link 1", "Click", null, new { @id = "Link1", @data_val = "1", @class = "links" })
        @Html.Hidden("id", "");
    }
```

**SCRIPT**:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('a[class=links]').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("input#id").val($(this).attr("data-val"));
            $('form#myAjaxForm').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

**CONTROLLER**:

```
    public ActionResult Click()
    {
        var m = new MyModel();
        return View(m);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Click(string id)
    {
        return Content("ID = " + id, "text/html");
    }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use a separate forms per button (which contrary to classic WebForms is something that you should not be afraid of in ASP.NET MVC) and of course use submit buttons instead of hyperlink which are the semantically correct element to submit a form:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Click", new { id = "0" }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "showpage" }))
{
    <button type="submit" value="Link 0" />
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Click", new { id = "1" }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "showpage" }))
{
    <button type="submit" value="Link 1" />
}
```

Now inside your `Click` action you will get the correct id.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of hyperlinks you can use submit buttons with the `name` property.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Click", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "showpage" }))
{
   <input type="submit" name="action" value="0" />
   <input type="submit" name="action" value="1" />
}

public ActionResult Click(string action, ... )
{
   // Action here
}
```