# Passing Id from javascript to Controller in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How to pass Id from javascript to Controller action in mvc3 on ajax unobtrusive form submit

My script

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tblclick td[id]").each(function (i, elem) {

            $(elem).click(function (e) {
                var ID = this.id;
                alert(ID);
               // var url = '@Url.Action("Listpage2", "Home")'; 
                var data = { Id: ID };
//                  $.post(url,data, function (result) {
//                 }); 
                e.preventDefault();
                $('form#myAjaxForm').submit();
            });
                       });
    });
</script>
```

the how to pass Id on using   $('form#myAjaxForm').submit(); to controller
instead of

```
$.post(url,data, function (result) {
    //                 });
```

My View

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Listpage2", "", new AjaxOptions
            {
                UpdateTargetId = "showpage"
            }, new { @id = "myAjaxForm" }))
            {

                <table id="tblclick">
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.names.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td id='@Model.names[i].Id'>
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.names[i].Name, Model.names[i].Name, new { @id = Model.names[i].Id })
                              <br />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>

            }
        </td>
        <td id="showpage">
        </td>
```

Comment: Could you shows the sign of your action?

Comment: does this "$('form#myAjaxForm').submit()" do anything special or different than redirecting to the controller? If you just need redirected to the action with the correct ID i can help

Comment: Yes i want that way @JohnSykor

Comment: ok I undeleted my method(answer) that I removed after seeing the changes made to the post because I was unsure if my answer would apply with the ajax but I know I currently use it in a redirect on click function and I was hoping you would find it useful for your situation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405832/recognize-particular-id-in-ajax-form-mvc3-from-several-hyperlink

Using this example you can send Id to Controller class

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure for $.post but I know window.location works great for me.
Use this instead and hopefully you have good results :)

```
window.location = "@(Url.Action("Listpage2", "Home"))" + "Id=" + ID;
```

replace $('form#myAjaxForm').submit(); with this code and nothing looks blatantly wrong with your jscript.

Comment: place '?' sign before Id to make it parameter window.location = "@(Url.Action("Listpage2", "Home"))" + "?Id=" + ID;

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using the Ajax `Beginform` helper method and do some pure handwritten and **Clean** javascript like this

```
<table id="tblclick">
  @foreach(var name in Model.names)
  {
    <tr>
     <td id="@name.Id">
           @Html.ActionLink(name.Name,"listpage","yourControllerName", 
                         new { @id = name.Id },new { @class="ajaxShow"})         
     </td>
    </tr>
   }
</table>

<script>
 $(function(){
    $(".ajaxShow")click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $("#showpage").load($(this).attr("href")); 
    });
 });
</script>
```

This will generate the markup of anchor tag in your for each loop like this.

```
<a href="/yourControllerName/listpage/12" class="ajaxShow" >John</a>
<a href="/yourControllerName/listpage/35" class="ajaxShow" >Mark</a>
```

And when user clicks on the link, it uses jQuery `load` function to load the response from thae `listpage` action method to the div with id `showPage`.

Assuming your `listpage` action method accepts an id parameter and returns something

Answer (score 0):

Just use a text box helper with html attribute ID.

```
@Html.TextBox("ID")
```

You can do this too:

```
 var form = $('form#myAjaxForm');
 $.ajax({
       type: "post",
       async: false,
       url: form.attr("action"),
       data: form.serialize(),
       success: function (data) {
          // do something if successful
          }
 });
```

Comment: I want to send it from javascript which i obtained var ID =this.id;

Comment: Why don't you want to use $.post then?

Comment: I am submiting an unobstrusive ajax form where i dont want my view to postback

Comment: How to send and retrieve Id in Controller class

Comment: Create textbox like I said and in your javascript do `$("form #ID").val(id);`